# Office 2019 Not Updating From Local CDN

Tags: cdn, microsoft-office-2019

I have setup an offline CDN for my clients that are on our offline networks to keep their Office 2019 installations up to date. Initial installation of our Office 2019 installer installs version 16.0.10350.20019. Using the Office 2019 administrative templates the clients are checking a network share with the latest Office CDN information.

The clients have been checking and updating to 16.0.10351.20054 without an issue. As of recently the latest update from the online CDN is 16.0.10352.20042. I have copied the data over from the online CDN to my Offline CDN. For some reason the Office 2019 clients think they are up to date at 16.0.10351.20054.

Has anyone had this issue yet or know where I can check a log into the client attempting to update?

Comment: *16.0.10352.20042* is an earlier build than what your users have installed (per what you wrote)

Comment: @Ramhound. The 20054 is part of 10351. 20042 is part of 10352

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boy do I feel silly. Upon further investigation and looking at some information on the microsoft site we found that the v64.cab file was not updated when the online CDN was ran. Upon rerunning the download the v64.cab was updated and moved it to our offline network and the upgrade started without a problem.

We will check the dates of modification when newer versions come down.